# How can I add condition in href on vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-bg">
        <li role="presentation">
            <a :href="baseUrl+'/search/store/'+param">
                Store
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['type', 'param'],
    }
</script>
```

I want to add condition in href

If type = 'a' then href =

```
<a :href="baseUrl+'/search/store/'+param">Store</a>
```

If type = 'b' then href =

```
<a href="javascript:">Store</a>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to create computed property:

```html
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['type', 'param'],
        computed: {
          url () {
            return this.type === 'a'
              ? `${this.baseUrl}/search/store/${this.param}`
              : 'javascript:'
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and temple will be:

```html
<a :href="url">Store</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operators can be good for this. For example:

```
<a :href="type == 'a' ? baseUrl+'/search/store/'+param : 'javascript:'">Store</a>
```

Alternatively, use `v-if`:

```
<a v-if="type == 'a'" :href="baseUrl+'/search/store/'+param">Store</a>
<a v-else-if="type == 'b'" :href="'javascript:'">Store</a>
```

Comment: I was looking for a syntax without JS intervention. Thanks.